# How to determine which server IP address the client connected to

Tags: .net, sockets, networking, c#-4.0

I'm binding with IPAddress.Any.  My server has multiple IP addresses.  In my case all on the same NIC but I don't think that matters -- it could be just as easily multiple NIC.

I need to know which IP address the client has connected to.  Is this possible, or should I create different sockets for each of my Ipaddresses and bind to each one?

Update:
Creating a TcpListener for each of the IP Addresses as proven to be the easiest solution, although I remain open to other suggestions related to IPAddress.Any (0.0.0.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TcpClient.Client.LocalEndPoint` should contain the correct IP Address.